# Scala function return type

Tags: scala, function, traits

I'm trying to change a method into a function, but I'm having troubles with the return type:

```
sealed trait CronJobStatus
case object CronJobSuccess extends CronJobStatus
case class CronJobFailure(error: Option[String] = None) extends CronJobStatus
```

My method (which works) is:

```
def jobNotFoundFailure(name: String): CronJobStatus = CronJobFailure(Some(s"Job with name $name not found"))
```

When trying to have jobNotFoundFailure as a function, I'm unable to find the right syntax to specify that it returns a CronJobStatus, I've got this function (but it returns CronJobFailure)

```
val jobNotFoundFailure = (name: String) => CronJobFailure(Some(s"Job with name $name not found"))
```

Which means I can't use this function where a CronJobStatus is expected. e.g. when getting an Opt from a map and folding:

```
cronJobsMap.get(name).fold(jobNotFoundFailure(name))(doDelete)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
val jobNotFoundFailure: String => CronJobStatus =
  name => CronJobFailure(Some(s"Job with name $name not found"))
```

Comment: Tried for over half an hour searching for the syntax but could not find it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option is:

```
val jobNotFoundFailure = (name: String) =>
  CronJobFailure(Some(s"Job with name $name not found")): CronJobStatus
```

By the way your code (ignoring the fact that I don't know how `doDelete` looks like) seems to work even if jobNotFoundFailure is `String => CronJobFailure`.

```
cronJobsMap.get(name).fold(jobNotFoundFailure(name))(doDelete)
```

Whenever `CronJobStatus` is needed you can put `CronJobFailure`. Wherever function `A => CronJobStatus` is needed `A => CronJobFailure` is also valid because `Function1[-T, +R]` is covariant in the type of returned value.